# How to make the mouseover ease in opacity

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, mouseover, easing

I have buttons that change in opacity when I hover over them. I would like them to slowly change with easing.  How do I do this with jquery?

Comment: Easiest way is to use CSS3 transitions.

Comment: But is that multi-browser friendly?

Comment: Jquery easing Plugin? http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is utilizing CSS3 Transitions:

```
element{
   -webkit-transition:color .5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
   -moz-transition: color .5s; /* Firefox */
   -o-transition: color .5s; /* Opera */
   transition:color .5s;
}
```

Most current browsers support this. Check out [this page](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions) for a full list of browser compatibility. Unless you need to target Internet Explorer >10 or really old versions of Firefox and Opera, you should be fine.